# Splash Screen making app crash

Tags: android, splash-screen

I added splash screen to my application however it make my app crash. Here's the thing the Splash Screen is showing however it doesn't start my MainActivity. Help guys. See my Manifest..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Splash">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.billeazy.SPLASH" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: It's always super helpful if you have a crash to actually TELL US WHAT THE CRASH WAS.

Comment: Your "Splash" activity need to be `MAIN`.

Comment: This practice is frowned upon, for the correct way to do a splash screen on Android see here: https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/Z1Wwainpjhd

Comment: @Stanojkovic what do you mean it need to be main?

Comment: @Joseph Tatel a nice example is given by userJP below.

Answer (score 1):

Your "Splash" activity need to be MAIN LAUNCHER Activity. So modify the `AndroidManifest` file like this...

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Splash">
        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

And Jump to MainActivity after few seconds..

```
Handler hadler=new Handler();
        hadler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run () {
                finish();
                Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }, 3000);
```

here 3000 is used for 3 seconds. The MainActivity auto start after 3 seconds.
Hope it helps.